# react native header title position

Tags: navigation, styles, react-native

[image]

how can I change position of header title to right in react native:

code is:

```
Home: {
screen: BookViewContainer ,
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  headerRight: <DrawerIcon iconDefault='menu' tintColor={Constants.styles.secondColor} size={30}/>,
  title: Strings.book_label,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Constants.styles.mainColor
  },
  headerTintColor: Constants.styles.secondColor
})},
```

In ios it's show title in center, back button in left, menu button in right and it's ok but for android i need to title in right and back button in left

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for android i added this line:

```
headerTitleStyle: {
   alignSelf: (Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'flex-end' : 'center'
}
```

for example for Home sense I use like below code:

```
Home: {screen: BookViewContainer , navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  title: 'test title',
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  headerTintColor: 'blue',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    alignSelf: (Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'flex-end' : 'center'
  }
 })},
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky way is to implement with `absolute` and `zindex` props, if you're using react-native-base

```
<Button transparent>
    <View style={{}}>
        <Icon name="more-vert" style={{
            zIndex:-999 ,
            position:'absolute',
            right:0,
            top:0,
            }}/>
        <Picker
            style={{
              zIndex:999,
              position:'absolute',
              //right:0,
              top:-35,
              backgroundColor:'transparent',
            }}
            onValueChange={()=>{}}
            mode="dropdown">
            <Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
            <Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
        </Picker>
    </View>  
</Button>
```

[image: see image here !!]